# Does the effective reluctance of an air gap between two windings increase from circulating air?

Tags: motor, inductor, electromagnetism, generator, lipo

If I have an inductor next to another copper coil (I don't exactly know the lingo for a coil receiving power from an inductor), and there is a significant but not large air gap between the two coils, will the reluctance change if more air is passing through the air gap? What I mean is that **I would like to change the reluctance of the air gap by pumping through a fast stream of air through the air gap.** *Will this increase the reluctance of the air gap?*

The application is a DC generator that can change the amount of power that is transferred between the rotating of a shaft by a human to a lipo. I would like a mode where the shaft can spin almost freely when circulating air is being pumped (in the case that the answer to my question is a yes), and a mode where the shaft is very hard to spin due to the horsepower of the generator. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "a fast stream of air" will not materially impact the reluctance. (But I'm also sure that there is a scientist out there who may be able to design the instrument that would measure the change for you, if you wanted to find out just how little the difference is.)

Comment: If the moving air has a slightly different density than the still air, there will be a very, very, very, very small change in reluctance. If I had to take a guess, I would say in the parts per million or less.

Comment: The only effect I have heard is a reduction in breakdown voltage on grid equipment with oil pumps and forced air cooling on Rogowski coils with HV causing partial Discharge (PD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to modify the airgap reluctance is to change its width, either by squeezing the pole pieces together (or stretching them apart), or inserting some ferromagnetic material. Decreasing the gap will reduce reluctance, increasing it will increase reluctance.

Indeed if you attempt to measure the changes in permeability of the air itself (e.g. using Bernoulli per another answer) you will need to consider the mechanical rigidity of the core, or the lowered pressure in the gap can pull the poles together enough to affect the very delicate measurement you would need.

More practically you can partially insert or withdraw a ferrous metal foil, or tapered wedge, or a blob of [ferrofluid](https://www.first4magnets.com/magnetic-ferrofluid-accessories-t173) (ferrous particles suspended in oil) and control its position with your stream of air.

Comment: In the first part of your answer, does inserting ferromagnetic material act as a conductor that absorbs the magnetic field of the two poles? Also, if I'm not mistaken, wouldn't squeezing the pole pieces closer to each other decrease the width of the air gap and decrease the reluctance between the two pole pieces? I just want to make sure that I completely understand the effect on reluctance from changing the width of the airgap based on the wording of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: oops I misread the question; or I was mentally confusing reluctance with susceptance. you are of course correct that reducing the gap  increases *susceptance*! For "increase" read "decrease" ... Editing (and feel free to un-accept if you want)..

Comment: That makes much more sense thank you! I will keep your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The relative permeability of air is about 1.0000004. A stream of air will decrease air pressure (Bernoulli principle) and thus slightly lower the relative permeability. But clearly this can only change within the range of 1.0000004 to 1 (vacuum) which is a change that is likely not detectable.